# Java FX Ant project to maven project

Tags: maven-2, netbeans, ant, javafx

I have a java fx project created in Netbeans IDE and I need to change it to a maven based project for the sake of uniform build process(company policies).

Is there any way I can convert the ant based javafx project(created in netbeans) to a maven project?

I tried finding some resources from google, but I could not find any standard way of doing it. Any help would be helpful.

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 0):

afaik, even if you convert the project to maven, you will not get any of the javafx editing features in the IDE then. (it was so the last time I checked, might have changed since then)